# Fill all available horizontal space in a stack

Tags: flutter, stack, containers, width, flutter-layout

Inside a card I have a stack with 1) an image and 2) a text inside a container.
How can I make the container width to fill the card width?

```
Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(child: Image.network(
          image_url,
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("test1"),
              Text("test2"),
              Text("test3"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `left` and `right` values to `0` so that the container will behave so.

```dart
Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(child: Image.network(
          image_url,
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("test1"),
              Text("test2"),
              Text("test3"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all the childrens with the `Expanded` widget.

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Text("test1")
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Text("test2")
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Text("test3")
        ),
    ],
),
```

From the [Expanded Widget Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html):

> Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column). If multiple children are expanded, the available space is divided among them according to the flex factor.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually stumbled across an answer using a stack, however, if anyone knows a way with the Columns/Rows I'd be interested to know...

```
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                // title
                Text(
                  title,
                  style: baseStyle,
                ),

                // underline
                Positioned.fill(
                  top: null,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 4,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```